# Solr collapse does not collapse result set like group feature on Solr tutorial index

Tags: solr

Solr collapse does not work as expected.
I am using Solr 8.7 on Ubuntu 20.04. The index being used is the example index found on the Solr tutorial.

While applying collapse on a field with integers or single valued strings, there are multiple results of the same value of the field.

Trying this - `http://localhost:8983/solr/library/select?fq=%7B!collapse%20field%3Dauthor%7D&q=*` which is basically - `fq = {!collapse field=author}` ends up in error - `Error from server at null: Collapsing field should be of either String, Int or Float type` while the field is singular string type.

Trying the same with `popularity` field gives multiple results of same popularity.

While trying all these with `...&group=true&groupid=author` gives single result for particular field value, as expected.

Comment: What is the _actual_ field type of the `author` field? What does it show if you display the field under the Solr admin page? What is returned if you query the field from a document? The error happens if the field isn't a StrField or it isn't collapsible to a numeric type.

Comment: Thank you for your response. author field shows type - `org.apache.solr.schema.SortableTextField` popularity field shows - `org.apache.solr.schema.IntPointField`.

 I had tried another field genre_s - `org.apache.solr.schema.StrField`

Comment: Then you're going to have to use a `StrField` for the field instead of a text field - your current type isn't supported by the collapsing query parser. It needs to be a `string` - i.e. a field that is defined with `StrField` as its base type. You'll have to reindex after setting the type explicitly. You might have an `author_s` field automagically populated as well for use in cases like this (since the default schema uses the schemaless mode by default iirc).

Comment: Ah yes, I got it. 'author' field is not String type and so gives the error. But then what about the 'popularity' field? It is Int field type. Why does it not work with collapse but works with group command?

Comment: Because it's a TrieField - trie fields work by indexing several tokens for the field to support quicker resolution. You're seeing the different tokens being returned and represented as the canonical int value (so they seem similar).

Comment: Thanks a lot MatsLindh. That makes some sense now. I'll try collapsing with fields specified in the xml then.